# Push Notification not receiving some times in iphone from Parse.com server

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I'm using **parse server** to send and receive **push notification** I have completed all formalities which i have to do for configuring push notification. **I have also checked that I got  device token for push notification.**  My issue is when I'm sending push notification for my app, Parse server shows related push notification has been sent but at receiving end push notification is not receiving some times. Can somebody explain me why this is happening. Do I need to configure from server side or my side? This is happening randomly. Help would be appreciable.

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html , "Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that there is new data available."

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that there is no guarantee that **all** your sent notifications will be received.

Apple says in [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html):

> Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is
>   not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that
>   there is new data available.

Comment: thanks for your answer but would you tell me that how and when notify user that some data available???

Comment: You can send more than once, or if you have a critical data like a chat app you can use socket based app, or app needs refresh you can use ios7 background task, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I'm working on chat application. app is working fine but now I've implemented push notification to notify the user that you have got a message if app at the user end is in background. I've implemented successfully and push notification working fine but sometime push notification is not receiving at user end. what could be the problem?